# Adjacency matrix of a square of a graph.

Tags: graph-theory

> What is the relation between $A(G)$ and $A(G^2)$?

Where $G^2$ is [the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power) of a graph $G$ and $A(G^2),A(G)$ their respective [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

Comment: I think you shroud look at diagonal of $A(G^2)$

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear (and self-contained). Please check if the edit is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G^2$ is the graph with the same set of vertices as $G$, but with edges connecting vertices with distance $\leq 2$ in $G$.

$A(G)$ shows which vertices in $G$ have a distance of 1. $A(G^2)$ shows which vertices in $G^2$ have a distance of $1$, or a distance of $\leq 2$ in $G$.

So, $A(G^2) - A(G)$ shows which vertices in $G$ have a distance of exactly 2. This difference would have non-zero, non-diagonal entries in the same places as $[A(G)]^2$ (where $A_{ij}^{2}$ is the number of walks of length $2$ between vertices $i$ and $j$).

Comment: Genius, that is awesome!